# Configuring Restivus POST method for Meteor

Tags: rest, http, curl, meteor, routes

I have the following Restivus configuration:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

    Restivus.configure({
    });

    //Allow Restivus to manage Reports
    Restivus.addCollection('reports');

    Restivus.addRoute('newReport/:message', {}, {

        // POST
        post: {
            action: function(){

                var response = null;
                var message = this.urlParams.message;

                if(message){
                    console.log("Message received: " + message);
                    return {status: "success", data: message};
                } else {
                    console.log("Message empty...");
                    return {status: "fail", message: "Post not found"};
                }

                //Response to caller
                return;
            }
        }
    })

}
```

Following the explanation of Restivus, when I make a GET call to `http://localhost:3000/api/newReport/` I should get a "Get All" result from the server, on the caller.

However, if I use `curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/newReport/` on the command line, I seem to be getting the HTML code of the site at api/NewReport/ (which is empty, except for the header and empty body)

Knowing that, I know my error is in the Restivus Route configuration, but I cannot pinpoint the reason.

The expected behavior is that when I make a POST from a Ruby script, I should get a returned message (Ok or Fail), and in my Meteor console, I should see either "Message received" or "Post not found" (both placeholders).

Additional question, is there a way to disable the default GET method Restivus creates when we add a collection?

Comment: If you did as Michael suggested below, you would have had a "get all" endpoint defined at `/api/reports`. You never setup any route at `api/newReport` (only `api/newReport/:message`), so you were receiving the default meteor template. The answer to your other question is yes. See the docs here: https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus#excludedendpoints

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a variable in the JavaScript part and use that in the Restivus.addCollection() call.

```
Reports = Mongo.Collection('reports')

if(Meteor.isServer){

    Restivus.configure({
    });

    //Allow Restivus to manage Reports
    Restivus.addCollection(Reports);
...
```

Comment: I tried that before and it still didn't work. I ended up not using Restivus for my REST operations, but thank you.

Comment: This was half of the problem. I've left a comment above explaining the rest of the issue. Thanks for providing this info!